# Need to add multiple items in list - decision table - Drools

Tags: java, object, arraylist, jboss, drools

I need to create a new multiple instance of objects for the Pojo class in drools decision table. I have implemented using two facts Student fact and subject fact class. I need to fire all the rules in the decision table and I need to add all the values into array-list of the objects. But I'm getting only last rule values of decision table. It seems like decision table values are getting overridden.

**Fact 1**

```
Class StudentFact{

 private int id;
 private String name;
 private List<SubejctFact> subjectList;

 public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
 }

 public int getId(){
    return id;
 } 

 public void setName(String name){
    this.Name = name;
 }    

 public String getName(){
    return name;
 }

     public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }



    public int getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }




}
```

**Fact 2**

```
Class SubjectFact{
 private int subId;
 private String subjectName;

 public void setSubId(int subId){
     this.subId= subId;
 }

 public int getSubId(){
   return subId;
 }

 public void setSubjectName(String subjectName){
      this.subjectName = subjectName;
 }

 public int getSubejctName(){
      return subjectName;
 }

}
```

**Current Response**

```
{
  "id":123,
  "name": "xyz",
  "subjectList": [
     { 
        "id": 6,
        "name":"Hindi"
     },
     {
        "id": 6,
        "name":"Hindi"
     }
}
```

**Expected Response**

```
 {
      "id":123,
      "name": "xyz",
      "subjectList": [
         { 
            "id": 5,
            "name":"English"
         },
         {
            "id": 6,
            "name":"Hindi"
         }
    }
```

My Decision Table  looks like

[image]

Any one pls advise to achieve the expected response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each row in a table becomes a rule, each action column becomes a row in then block.
For each rule you need a statement to create Subject, statements to populate it and statement to add it to matching student.
Values in 'CREATE' and 'COLLECT' are needed, otherwise action will be skipped.
`;` is required in a cell without 'target object' and it is not required when you provide '$subject' and '$student' objects. Don't ask me why. Just analyzed generated drl.
You may want to hide two 'technical columns'.

[image]

This will generate two rules like below

```
package draft;
//generated from Decision Table
import draft.Student;
import draft.Subject;
// rule values at A9, header at A4
rule "Rule 1"
    when
        $student:Student(id == "123")
    then
        Subject $subject = new Subject();
        $subject.setSubId(5);
        $subject.setSubjectName('English');
        $student.addSubject($subject);
end

// rule values at A10, header at A4
rule "Rule 2"
    when
        $student:Student(id == "123")
    then
        Subject $subject = new Subject();
        $subject.setSubId(6);
        $subject.setSubjectName('Hindi');
        $student.addSubject($subject);
end
```

PS: I was struggling with `"` being automatically replaced by Calc editor to `` which was not valid symbol for drools parser, so I used single quotes, which appeared to be special symbol at the start of a cell in the editor and skipped. So actual cell value which finally worked for me was `''English'`.

Here are my models

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
        subjectList.add(subject);
    }
    
    public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }
    
    public List<Subject> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }
}

public class Subject {
    private int subId;
    private String subjectName;
    
    public void setSubId(int subId) {
        this.subId = subId;
    }
    
    public int getSubId() {
        return subId;
    }
    
    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }
    
    public String getSubejctName() {
        return subjectName;
    }
}
```

test

```
@DroolsSession(resources = "draft/ApplicableSubjects.xls",
        builderProperties = "drools.dump.dir = target/dump")
public class PlaygroundTest {
    
    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();
    
    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        drools.insertAndFire(new Student(123, "Student 123"));
        drools.printFacts();
    }
}
```

test output

```
00:00:00 --> inserted: Student[id=123,name=Student 123,subjectList=[]]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 <-- 'Rule 1' has been activated by the tuple [Student]
00:00:00 <-- 'Rule 2' has been activated by the tuple [Student]
00:00:00 Facts (1):
Student[id=123,name=Student 123,subjectList=[draft.Subject@1ded7b14, draft.Subject@29be7749]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mykhaylo. I tried your solution. Still I'm getting only last rule values.I need to add it as Array list as I mentioned before in (subjectList) . Can you please advise on this?

Comment: I added all sources I have, are you saying you've edited the table like requested? Please show me generated rules of your table.

Comment: Yeah @Mykhaylo. I updated decision table as you suggested.In the solution above you mentioned is adding a Single Object Subject to the Student Fact. This is working for me !!!
My Requirement is need to add list of Subjects to Student Fact.
From the above mentioned example I'm getting this result:
{
  "id":123,
  "name": "xyz",
  "subject":
     {
        "id": 6,
        "name":"Hindi"
     }
}

Comment: Can you please advise on the above comment? One more thing can you please suggest me possible ways to create a variable in decision table ? If possible.

Comment: each table row add a subject, as a result of 2 matching rows your student should have list of 2 subjects populated according to the table data, not sure what are you asking about

Comment: didn't we create a variable $subject?

Comment: added test output

Comment: Thanks Mykhaylo. Finally I achieved the solution by your suggestion. Last Question - Sorry for this.- Any possible way create object without mentioning in condition section ?

Comment: Not sure I understand you question again, are you talking about `$student: ` definition? You need reference to student to add subjects to it somehow...

Comment: If you are talking about `$subject` object definition, it was not mentioned in condition section, it was mentioned in action (RHS)

Comment: Yeah I seen- It was mentioned in Action part,but $subject will invoke for each rule right?. Just curious if I need to create multiple objects like $personalnformaton $contactInformation for specific rules alone? Is it possible ? without declariing it in condition or action ?. I'm aware we can use it variables section but it not working as above. Please correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: You can design Student class whenever your imagination go. Introduce builder API there, create inner two dimensional array and expose methods to fulfill it. You told that you need a 'list of subjects for a student'. You would need to instantiate an object to fulfill the list, don't you? That's the answer for your question, you need multiple objects because you designed your models this way. It doesn't mean you must create them with `new` keyword in a spreadsheet, you can create it somewhere deep inside student object and expose builder method. Whatever you design it.