# KIE Workbench Decision tables not giving any result

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

This is my rule file;

```
package com.myspace.sample;

import com.myspace.sample.lookupValue;

rule "5 Year Loan"
    when
        LK:lookupValue(type=="5 Year")
    then
        LK.setValue("5");
end


rule "7 Year Loan"
    when
        LK:lookupValue(type=="7 Year")
    then
        LK.setValue("4.8");
end


rule "10 Year Loan"
    when
        LK:lookupValue(type=="10 Year")
    then
        LK.setValue("4");
end
```

This is my Object Model

```
package com.myspace.sample;

public class lookupValue implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label(value = "name")
    private java.lang.String name;
    @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label(value = "type")
    private java.lang.String type;
    @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label(value = "value")
    private java.lang.String value;

    public lookupValue() {
    }

    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public java.lang.String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(java.lang.String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public java.lang.String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(java.lang.String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: would you provide an example to execute and reproduce you problem?

Comment: When i executing a JSON reuqest against all rules. I am not getting and values back.

Comment: do you see 'edit' in the list of buttons below your question? you can change your original question and format your code better. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: please edit the question and add all the useful information and the example with expected and actual result that you're getting so we can help you. no one have super power here that can understand your problem without a well asked question.

Comment: you can paste images which would be good to have for a table, not to spend hours of formatting, see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097561/need-to-add-multiple-items-in-list-decision-table-drools)

Comment: updated with model and rule file generated from decision table.

Comment: @Mykhaylo Adamovych i am unable to paste images as my stack overflow level is low.
However i have updated the description and also pasted my rule file generated from decision table and also the data object model in description of the issue.

Comment: @Bashir i have updated the description with data model and rule file.

Comment: refer to this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/H4_HzpAmKRI. Here you will be able to understand the problem much easier