# Drools, unable to access HashMap in Decision Table Action

Tags: drools

I am unable to access Rules hashmap in ACTION column for Drools Decision Table. I am getting null pointer exception or eof input exception.The ACTION column of `rulesReq.get("<key>")` is not working. How can I access HashMap in the ACTION column?

[image: Screenshot of decision table]

Answer (score 0):

1. Having `$rulesReq.get("<key>")` in action column is fine, but when you define variable (it is done implicitly when you combine variable cells) you should write your code relative to that variable, for example `get("<key>")`.
2. What do you what to achieve when you put the code into the value section?

See [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123592/448078) in another post.