# How to pass an object only to ACTION section of the decision table?

Tags: java, kotlin, drools

I am trying to achieve the following with Drools decision tables: I want to use one read-only object as input for my rules, and one mutable object where actions would store the appropriate results. However, so far I wasn't able to find an elegant way to do this, other than the ugly hack showed on the picture: using one "dummy" condition column just to declare the output object.

[Sample decision table showing the hack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVaoJ.png)

If I declare the output object in action section just like the input one in condition section, I always get "$output could not be resolved" kind of errors. Declaring the output in the same cell as input might also be a viable option, but I couldn't achieve that either - separating them with commas or just whitespaces resulted in all sorts of errors.

Here's the code (Kotlin language) I'm currently using to run Drools:

```
private fun calculatePrice(input: RuleInput, path: String): RuleOutput {
    val kieRepository: KieRepository = kieServices.repository
    kieRepository.addKieModule { kieRepository.defaultReleaseId }
    val kb: KieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(prepareFileSystem(kieServices, path))
    kb.buildAll()
    val kieModule: KieModule = kb.kieModule
    val kieContainer: KieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.releaseId)
    val output = RuleOutput()
    kieContainer.newKieSession().apply {
        insert(input)
        insert(output)
        fireAllRules()
    }
    return output
}
```

Comment: I mean, you're doing it the right way, not sure why you call it a "ugly hack"? Alternatively you could declare it as a global.

Comment: Well, I called it an ugly hack because I had to create one useless condition column (which is always true for every rule) just to be able to access this object. I think this decreases readability of the decision table - this condition doesn't have any logical purpose for this case.
Could you elaborate on how to declare it as a global?

Answer (score 0):

You can create output variable in the first action cell and declare it as a variable for the following actions. For your example E7 cell could have the following

```
RuleOutput $output = new RuleOutput;
$output.setC($param);
```

Worth to note that any action will be ignored if respective data cell is empty. Thus above will work if you always have `C` parameter. Otherwise `$output` variable will not be defined.

But I can see more fundamental architectural issue than the problem you are trying to solve.  You should understand that each row becomes a rule and all of them could be executed but you have single input and single result. What do you expect to see written by multiple rules into single result object? It will be 'random mess' as there is no predefined rules execution order. So many rule may override `C` param in random order. The same with any other parameter. Thus you must have one to many relationship between input object and result. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123592/448078).